# Elastic Search using PHP not working

Tags: php, curl, elasticsearch

I am a very beginner of Elastic search.
and I want to create a node in php using Curl

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/movies/movie/1" -d'
{
    "title": "The Godfather",
    "year": 1972
}'
```

WITHOUT USING any open source like elastica i want to implement the above CURL,
I tried this-

```
<?
$url='curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/movies/movie/1" -d\' { "title": "The Godfather","year": 1972}\'';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
ob_start();
curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$data = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
var_dump($data);
?>
```

But neither its giving any output, nor node is created. What is the problem?
For initial usage I want the simplest php. I don't want to use [elastica](https://github.com/ruflin/Elastica) or any other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your equivalent curl code:

```
$url='http://localhost:9200/movies/movie/1';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"title": "The Godfather","year": 1972}');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("Content-Type: appliaction/json"));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Removing echo the CURLOPT_POST and replacing it with curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT'); made it work for me